# Wordpress: Limit the number of retults from get_the_term_list

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently using `<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'tag', '', '', '' ); ?>` to return the list of tags attached to a custom post type in index.php and single.php.

Some of the posts have upwards of 20 tags attached, I need to keep these but only display the top 5 on the page.

I've looked at a few options including `wp_get_object_terms` and `get_objects_in_term` but can't seem to get the right combination of arguments.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-includes/category-template.php#L1111) for get_the_term_list, there's a filter you can attach to which processes the terms before they're output, so if you put the following in your functions.php:

```
add_filter( "term_links-tag", 'limit_terms');

function limit_terms($val) {
    return array_splice($val, 0, 5);
}
```

assuming, of course, that your taxonomy is called 'tag' - if not, change the filter name accordingly.

Comment: Bear in mind you can make it only show 5 depending on your current page too. Within the `limit_terms()` function you can use `is_archive()` or `is_home()` etc... so on single pages you'd still get the whole list of tags.